# Including time-specific measures

Tags: thesis

When writing a thesis or a research paper in general, is it advisable to include "time-specific measures" like

> [...] over the course of the last five years [...]

or

> Two years ago, it was discovered [...]

?

After all, if it is a working paper which gets published in a journal a few years after completion, the reader might get a wrong idea about when certain events happened in the past.

I wonder whether it is acceptable to include them nonetheless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Readers will tend to reference measures like this *from the publication date*, since that is typically the only information they have.  So if you write today, in 2017, that "five years ago, X happened" (i.e. in 2012), but then the article is not published until 2019 (which would be normal in some fields), then, as you say, the reader will mistakenly guess that X happened in 2014.

As such, I would avoid talking about specific numbers of years.  If the precise year is important, give the year ("in 2012, X happened").  If the year is not important, you can use less specific terms like "recently".

If you are writing for a conference, or another situation where you know for sure when the paper would be published, then such expressions would be more reasonable.  But it still means that a future reader may have to flip back to the article's title page to check the publication date, which can be a little distracting.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, will keep that in mind!